# Why can't I call gen_range with two i32 arguments?

Tags: function, random, methods, rust, numbers

I have this code but it doesn't compile:

```
use rand::Rng;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Guess the number!");

    let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0, 101);
    println!("The secret number is: {}", secret_number);

    println!("Please input your guess.");
    let mut guess = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut guess)
        .expect("Failed to read line");
    println!("You guessed: {}", guess);
}
```

Compile error:

```
error[E0061]: this function takes 1 argument but 2 arguments were supplied
 --> src/main.rs:7:44
  |
7 |     let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0, 101);
  |                                            ^^^^^^^^^ -  --- supplied 2 arguments
  |                                            |
  |                                            expected 1 argument
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, your question is rather vague. Please include what's not working e.g. any compiler or runtime error messages or wrong and expected values. Please [edit] your post. Also have a look at the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. :)

Comment: gen_range() method is not working

Comment: "gen_range() method is not working" still is vague, as it isn't clear whether the program does not compile at all or whether the behaviour is unexpected. Potential answerers then need to take additional steps, which might prolong the time till your question gets answered. You might want to keep that in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 19):

The [`gen_range`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.8.0/rand/trait.Rng.html#method.gen_range) method expects a single `Range` argument, not two `i32` arguments, so change:

```rust
let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0, 101);
```

to:

```rust
let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..101);
```

And it will compile and work. Note: the method signature was updated in version `0.8.0` of the `rand` crate, in all prior versions of the crate your code should work as-is.

Comment: or an inclusive `.gen_range(0..=100)`, which I personally prefer for readability.

Comment: @ismailshah if my answer fixed your problem please accept it by clicking the gray checkmark under the answer score, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

run cargo update
It will list the version for rand.

update the version in Cargo.toml  under dependencies

[dependencies]
rand = "0.8.3"

hopefully this solves the above problem