# Rust, rand gen_range wants 1 arg, not 2?

Tags: rust

I am following along the learn rust book from the rust lang website and random number generation is not working.

Specifically, when trying to create a random range like so:

```rust
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let s: u32 = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 101);
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

I get the error:

```sh
    Checking learn-rust v0.1.0 (.../learn-rust)
error[E0061]: this function takes 1 argument but 2 arguments were supplied
 --> src/main.rs:8:37
  |
8 |     let s: u32 = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 101);
  |                                     ^^^^^^^^^ -  --- supplied 2 arguments
  |                                     |
  |                                     expected 1 argument

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0061`.
error: could not compile `learn-rust`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

In the [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=008ca34af51b6e7bb6d78f3afd8cf1bb) I get the same error?

The version of rand on both local and playground is `0.8.0`.

Comment: [This was literally just asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65431713/why-cant-i-call-gen-range-with-two-i32-arguments) :)

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Why can't I call gen_range with two i32 arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65431713/2766908) but can't be closed as such since that doesn't have an accepted answer yet.

Comment: @pretzelhammer It doesn't need to be accepted, it just needs to be upvoted :)

Answer (score 19):

The easiest way to resolve an error like this is to [search for `gen_range` in the docs for the crate (rand)](https://docs.rs/rand/0.8.0/rand/?search=gen_range). You'll find that it's a [method of the `Rng` trait](https://docs.rs/rand/0.8.0/rand/trait.Rng.html#method.gen_range), and it takes a single argument: the range. So, supply it with a range:

```rust
rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1..101)
```